# Does Java have an equivalent to C#'s XML attributes?

Tags: java, serialization

Consider this C# code:

```
[XmlRoot("RootElementName")]
public class GetReportStatusResponse
{
    ....
}
```

This code allows me to express this class as `<RootElementName>` rather then `<GetReportStatusResponse>` when serialized to XML.

Does Java have an equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElementName")
public class GetReportStatusResponse {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html) here and it will support you